# Array access error in C

Tags: c, arrays, error-handling, char

i keep getting valgrind errors in my code and i have no idea how to fix it. :/
the idea is that no matter how much tabs / spaces are between 2 or more words/letters in an input, in the output it should be only one space.
for example:

```
a    b   c d -> a b c d
```

code:

```
char* echo(char* in) {
    char buffer[256];
    int incounter=0, buffcounter=0;

    while(incounter<(strlen(in))) {
        if(in[incounter] == ' ' || in[incounter] == '\t') incounter++;
        else if(in[incounter] != ' ' && in[incounter] != '\t') {
            while(in[incounter] != ' ' && in[incounter] != '\t') {
                buffer[buffcounter] = in[incounter];  //53
                incounter++;
                buffcounter++;              
            }           
            buffer[buffcounter] = ' ';
            buffcounter++;
        }
    }
    char* out = buffer;
    return out;
}
```

errors:

```
==20521== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20521==    at 0x4010B4: echo (hhush.c:53)
==20521==    by 0x4021CA: readCommand (hhush.c:327)
==20521==    by 0x402538: main (hhush.c:371)
==20521==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==20521==    at 0x402017: readCommand (hhush.c:301)
==20521== 
==20521== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20521==    at 0x4010CE: echo (hhush.c:53)
==20521==    by 0x4021CA: readCommand (hhush.c:327)
==20521==    by 0x402538: main (hhush.c:371)
==20521==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==20521==    at 0x402017: readCommand (hhush.c:301)
```

thats where i am now, still the same errors

```
char* echo(char* in,char* buffer){
    size_t inlen=strlen(in);
    int incounter=0,buffcounter=0;
    while(incounter<inlen){
        if(in[incounter]==' '||in[incounter]=='\t')incounter++;
        else{
            while(in[incounter]!=' '&&in[incounter]!='\t'){
                buffer[buffcounter]=in[incounter];
                incounter++;
                buffcounter++;              
            }           
            buffer[buffcounter]=' ';
            buffcounter++;
        }   
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

i call it with:

```
char input[256];
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
...
char buffer[256];
printf("%s\n",echo(input,buffer));
```

Comment: what makes you think that strlen(in) <= 255 ?

Comment: the function will never get called with a bigger input

Comment: Why do you compute `strlen(in)` in every loop iteration? It does not change. OTAH, I think this part can simply be removed `if(in[incounter] != ' ' && in[incounter] != '\t')`.

Comment: then the blanks wont be skipped

Comment: The inner while loop can run off the end of the input string

Comment: Still, the `else if (...) {` part can simply be an `else {` .

Comment: Will this loop miss copying the end of string character into the output array?  shouldn't cause the valgrind problem, I think, but ...

Comment: your are right, forgot that

Comment: that and if(!in[incounter])break; at the end of the while loop fixed it

Answer (score 4):

```
 char* out=buffer;
 return out;
}
```

Do not return a pointer to an array with automatic storage duration (here `buffer` array). If the pointer value is accessed, it invokes undefined behavior as automatic objects are discarded when the block where they are declared is exited (here when `echo` function returns).

Comment: @slyr To quickly check if it fixes the valgrind messages, just add the  `static` specifier in the array declaration.

Comment: @slyr in that case we also need to see how is called `echo` and how is its argument declared.

Comment: My guess is that this is what valgrind found, but there appear to be several other bugs in the program, not just this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the buffer outside of the function then you should pass the allocated buffer to the function.

```
void echo(char *in, char *buffer)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This way you won't be trying to access memory that has gone out of scope.

You can then use the function as such

```
char buffer[256];
echo(string, buffer);
```

The buffer should now contain your edited string.

Answer (score 0):

This message:

```
==20521== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20521==    at 0x4010B4: echo (hhush.c:53)
==20521==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==20521==    at 0x402017: readCommand (hhush.c:301)
```

is telling you that an `if` or `while` test on line 53 depends on uninitialzed data.  The data in question was allocated at line 301.  By looking at those lines, you should be able to tell what is going on, but it looks like you're allocating an array on the stack in `readCommand` and then passing it to `echo` as an argument, without ever putting anything in the array.  So your 'i call it with code' is *actually* something like:

```
char input[256];
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
...
char buffer[256];
printf("%s\n",echo(buffer));
```

and you're not passing what you think you're passing